# How to delete record in Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I'm learning Python with the tutorial app from Flask and I can't figure how to reference a certain row in the database. I m trying to delete a record by using the delete link in the template.I spent a whole day trying everything I could find and to really understand this. I know it's simple but I don't get it!

Here's the html template:

```
<ul class=entries>
{% for entry in entries %}
<li><h2>{{ entry.title }}
<h2>{{ entry.text|safe }}</h2>
{% if session.logged_in %}
<a href="{{ url_for('delete_entry') }}">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As you can see, next to each entry there's a delete link.How am I supposed to reference the
right id in the database?

Here's the Python function I have so far:

```
@app.route('/delete')
def delete_entry():
if not session.get('logged_in'):
    abort(401)
g.db.execute('delete from entries where id=(select max(id)from entries)') 
g.db.commit()
flash('The entry was deleted')
return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

What I have so far works but It's not what I want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited my answer you have now the complete code to make it work in Flask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sebastien the delete_entry function is deleting the last entry in the db

`where id=(select max(id)from entries)`

What you have to do is insert a parameter in the url for deletion like '/delete/:id' where the id is the id of the entry you want deleted, then change the template to generate the url as so:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('delete_entry', entry.id) }}">Delete</a>
```

And also change the db query that deletes the entry:

```
g.db.execute('delete from entries where id=' + id)
```

Edit1:

I checked the Flask documentation, in order to get variables into your routes you have to modify the route as follows:

```
@app.route('/delete/<int:entry_id>')
```

In this way you obtain the entry_id in your python function:

```
def delete_entry(entry_id):
g.db.execute('delete from entries where id=' + entry_id)
```

And finally you have to specify your entry id in the url_for function:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('delete_entry', entry_id = entry.id) }}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.I m getting a Werkzeug"BuildError: ('delete_entry, entry.id', {}, None) but I m going to read about Werkzeug more. At least, now I understand more. I won't keep looking in the wrong places.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to put the argument in the function...oops!

Comment: how come this :g.db.execute('delete from entries where id=' + entry_id)  Gives me this:cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.I know that id is an integer but why does it gets considered as a string here? Btw,why do you have to concatenate the id with entry_id?

Comment: I can't believe that all I had to do was: 

    entry_id=str(entry_id)
    g.db.execute('delete from entries where id=' +entry_id) 

The easiest way possible to convert an integer to a string and I tried everything else except that. Thanks again @Fernando!

Comment: Sorry I didn't read this until now... well I'm glad you could find your way through. Congrats!